# With the texshade package, is it possible to set a specific, non-Postcript font?

Tags: fonts, postscript, helvetica

I am using Helvetica Neue for the captions of my figures. I would like to keep this font for the sequence names in an alignment created using the texshade package.

On page 41 of the texshade manual, it is written that
"...including PostScript fonts is very easy. Just declare in the document header
\usepackage{⟨PS-font ⟩}...bookman.sty sets Bookman as \rmdefault, Avantgarde as \sfdefault and Courier as \ttdefault."

My knowledge and understand of how Latex deals with fonts is very poor so I can only guess that I am limited to sets of postscript fonts that I need to invoke by loading the corresponding packages.

Would it be possible to redefine \sfdefault to Helvetica Neue for example within the texshade environment?

Alternatively, is there a list somewhere of the available packages that will help me find a close alternative to Helvetica Neue?

Edit:
I am adding some info of about how my fonts are defined

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Helvetica Neue for the figure captions:

```
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, textformat=simple]{caption}%make the 'figure x' text in bold in the caption
\newcommand{\capft}{\fontspec{Helvetica Neue}\fontsize{8}{11}\selectfont}%define font for captions
\DeclareCaptionFont{capft}{\capft}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{bar}{ | }
\captionsetup{font=capft,labelsep=bar}
```

for the main text:

```
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
```

...and this is how a texshade environment inside a figure looks like:

```
\begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{texshade}{somefile.aln}
            \setfont{names}{rm}{md}{up}{footnotesize}
            \setfont{numbering}{rm}{md}{up}{footnotesize}
            \setends{1}{1..411}
            \shadingmode{similar}
            \shadingcolors{grays}
            \conservedresidues{White}{Black}{}{}
            \featurestylenamesrm \featurestylenamesit
          \end{texshade}
        \caption{some caption text}
        \label{fig:myfigure}
    \end{figure}
```

PS: I believe this question is quite specific to the texshade package but I do not have enough reputation points to create a texshade tag for the question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Can you post a `MWE` of what you tried till now?

Comment: @MadyYuvi Thanks for your comment. I do not think an MWE would bring any valuable info...and it would require an alignment file if you really wanted to test it. Besides I have not tried anything special, my alignment is working fine, I just do not know how to proceed and I am not sure I understand the manual and postscript fonts are.

Comment: Show a short but complete example,  that makes it much easier to test solutions.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer. As I wrote to MadyYuvi, this is too cumbersome for me to do so and an alignment file would be needed. There is nothing to test 
 anyway, I am just asking if sfdefault can be defined other than by loading a postscript package.

Comment: You wrote in your question understanding how latex deals with fonts is very poor.  Why do you think that you know better than me or MadyYuvi if a test document is useful or not?

Comment: I just know how difficult it is going for me to provide you such test document, I will have to strip many non-relevant bits of a very long latex document and also find a way to provide you an alignment file, and I have no idea how. I am just not willing to put that much effort to solve this question and if it is not something trivial to solve without a MWE, I will just delete it. Thank you very much for reading it anyway.

Comment: I have never used texshade and I won't start to read a large docu to find out how to use it only to tell you how to adapt its fonts. I also won't spent my time to extract from you how exactly you managed to use Helvetica Neue in your document. But if you provide a short test document showing your font setup and short texshade sequence it will probably take me only five minutes to find out where the font setting is. So it is your choice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using this in the texshade environment

```
\setsansfont{Helvetica Neue Light}
```

sets sfdefault to Helvetica Neue Light. That's all.

The question now is why experts need a MWE to provide such a simple answer...

Comment: There are several reasons why people might ask for a MWE. One is that it tells us what other packages you’re loading and whether they require any workarounds. For example, in this case, you told us that you’re loading `fontenc` in addition to `fontspec`, which is a mistake. If you were loading any legacy font packages, they might break. You might need a workaround for some math packages if you load `fontspec`, or to load `unicode-math`. Etc.

Comment: Another is that, when you put together a MWE, you were able to find the answer for yourself very quickly.

Comment: Thank you @Davislor for your comment. You are giving me general valid reasons for asking someone a MWE. The simple answer to my question (how to redefine \sfdefault) obviously does not require any (answer is to use the command \setsansfont). That is why you can only tell me about the fontenc mistake in my code (thank you for that by the way, I do appreciate the extra info) which was not the cause (or not even a clue to the solution) of my problem. Also I can assure you I was not able to find the solution because of the bits of code I posted, I do not know why you think it is the case.

Comment: @Cabin `MWE` helps to find the problem exactly where it lies and help to give exact solution, some times using of many packages and ordering of packages also may cause the error, hence `MWE` is a must....

Comment: @Cabin We don’t know for sure that it really is that simple until we see the MWE.

Comment: Folks, no need to downvote a perfectly working solution that may help someone else in the future because I have hurt your ego.